# How to disable browser autocomplete for the login form

Tags: 8, forms

I would like to remove auto fill user name and password while login or forgot password.

I have tried this but its not working:

```
if ($form_id == 'user-login-form') {
  $form['name']['#attributes']['autocomplete'] = 'off';
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Form IDs will have an _ not a - so you need to use user_login_form If you do print $form_id; within your form_alter function each form id will appear next to every form on the page allowing you to see its proper form id

Comment: yes you are right form id is `user_login_form  function` but still its not working my function is like this `use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase; use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface; myuser_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_login_form') {
$form['name']['#attributes']['autocomplete'] = 'off';
}
  return $form;
}` what  i'm missing

Comment: You don’t need to return anything it is passed by reference.

Comment: i have remove return $form still autocomplete is coming

Comment: Are you debugging it? Is this the right form item to alter? Is this code even firing? Is the module enabled?

Comment: yes this modules is enable

Comment: You're going to have to debug the work, we can't guess for you.

Comment: sorry Sir i dont have that much reputation :(

Comment: i'm tring to fix Autocomplete for login `xyz.zbc.com/user/login` field  for that i just create myuser modules in this modules i have myuser.info.yml and myuser.modules file

Comment: `<?php
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
function myuser_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == 'user_login_form') {
$form['name']['#attributes']['autocomplete'] = 'off';
}
}`

Comment: this code i have written in myuser.module file

Comment: It's probably `$form['account']['name']`.

Comment: @Jaypan The login form doesn't use `$form['account']['name']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$form['account']['name']['#attributes']['autocomplete'] = 'off';
```

Comment: The [`UserLoginForm`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Form%21UserLoginForm.php/class/UserLoginForm/9.0.x) class doesn't use `$form['account']['name']` but `$form['name']`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with Drupal - this is a browser issue. "autocomplete" is simply a suggestion to the browser, and the browser does not have to abide by that suggestion. Modern browsers (for at least 6 years now) have ignored it for username/password fields.

Search the web for "autocomplete=off not working" and you will find explanations and work-arounds.

As far as the `hook_form_alter()` goes, the simplest thing is to look at the generated HTML page for that form and see if you successfully added the `autocomplete="off"` attribute to the form tag. If it's not there, then you chose the wrong form ID, or you chose the wrong form element, etc. But as I said, even when you get the `hook_form_alter()` correct, the browser will probably ignore this attribute and you will have to use one of the work-arounds if you want this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Many modern browsers do not support autocomplete="off" for login fields
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#the_autocomplete_attribute_and_login_fields

If you still want to implement for browsers that allow, it this is an option for Drupal 9.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
   if ('user_login_form' == $form_id) {
    $form['#attributes']['autocomplete'] = 'off';
    $form['pass']['#attributes'] = ['autocomplete' => 'off'];
    $form['name']['#attributes'] = ['autocomplete' => 'off'];
  }
}
```